# Send parameters from server side to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to build a Shopify app. I am using `NodeJS` on the server side and `Angular 6` as the dashboard app inside Shopify for configs and stuff.

Shopify calls my app inside an iframe and has some query params in the link so i can identify which shop requested the app.

> https://myapp.com?shop=galaxy.myshopify.com

The issue i'm having is my server gets this request and responds with the Angular index.html file to it but i don't know how to give the `shop` param to the Angular app while it responds so i can have that `shop` param on client side for ajax calls.

So far I tried 2 things but they are not very elegant. First is to just read the query string when the app loads.

```
<script>
  window.GLOBALS = {
    query: window.location.search
  }
</script>
```

Another approach would be to read the params on the server side and transform the index.html into index.hbs and interpolate the params before sending the index file.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.hbs', { shop: req.query.shop });
});
```

and have the shop param in the `hbs` file

```
<script>
  window.GLOBALS = {
    shop: {{shop}}
  }
</script>
```

Is there any other way that would be more elegant ? Cause on first one, if i use any route, I lose the query params and in the second one I have to transform the index file every time i build the client.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: You could also use angular universal and thus provide the value directly to the app when it's rendered server side

Comment: How do you access params in angular that you feel you loose them?